# How to know the router's ExternalIPAddress on a Windows environment

Tags: router

The ports elements returned by asking for StaticPortMappingCollection in the HNetCfg.NATUPnP exposes a property for getting the router ExternalIPAddress.

Is it possible to get this value but without using NATUPnP?.

Thank you!